# How to control Graphical programs from terminal?

Tags: command-line, inkscape

I am trying to control Inkscape program from terminal; for example, I want to open the File menu, Edit menu or Extensions menu in Inkscape from the terminal without the need to click on the menu from the program itself.

I have searched a lot but I couldn't find an answer for my problem. How do I control Graphical programs from terminal?

Comment: See xdotool - http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that [ldtp](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/) can help you to automate Inkscape GUI. First open a terminal and install the python bindings:

```
sudo apt-get install python-ldtp
```

Then start the python interpreter:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ldtp import *
>>> launchapp('inkscape')
25362
>>> GTK Accessibility Module initialized
>>> selectmenuitem('*Inkscape', 'mnuExtensions')
```

or create a dedicated script with the following snippet:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from ldtp import *
import time

launchapp('inkscape')
waittillguiexist('*-Inkscape')
selectmenuitem('*-Inkscape', 'mnuExtensions')
time.sleep(2)
selectmenuitem('*-Inkscape', 'mnuEdit')
time.sleep(2)
selectmenuitem('*-Inkscape', 'mnuFile')
time.sleep(2)
selectmenuitem('*-Inkscape', 'mnuQuit')
waittillguinotexist('*-Inkscape')
```

Knowing all the GUI component names is a bit hard since `ldtpeditor` is deprecated (See [the freedesktop page](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/Howto_use_LDTP_Editor/) and [this thread on the freedesktop-ldtp-dev mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=freedesktop-ldtp-dev&m=139207808912396&w=1)).

The best you can do to identify the control to use to automate the application is to rely on [`getobjectlist)('<window name>')`](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/user-doc/d0/d4a/a00147.html).

**Example** (to set the Restack Horizontal point and the live preview):

[image]

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ldtp import *
>>> launchapp('inkscape')
11413
>>> GTK Accessibility Module initialized

>>> selectmenuitem('*Inkscape', 'Restack...')
1
>>> getobjectlist('Restack')
['dlgRestack', 'flr8', 'flr9', 'flr4', 'flr5', 'lblHorizontalPoint', 'flr7', 'flr0',
'flr1', 'flr2', 'flr3', 'lblVerticalPoint', 'mnuBottomtoTop(90)', 'mnuTop', 'spr1', 
'mnu8', 'flr11', 'mnu0', 'cboLefttoRight(0)', 'mnuRight', 'mnuRadialInward', 
'mnuMiddle1', 'mnu12', 'lblLivepreview', 'cboTop', 'flr6', 'mnuLefttoRight(0)', 
'btnApply', 'lblAngle', 'chk0', 'mnuRighttoLeft(180)', 'mnuRadialOutward', 'sbtn0', 
'mnuArbitraryAngle', 'lblRestackDirection', 'mnuLeft', 'btnClose', 'mnuMiddle', 
'mnuBottom', 'flr12', 'flr10', 'spr0', 'mnuToptoBottom(270)', 'cboMiddle']
>>> click('dlgRestack', 'mnuMiddle1')
1
>>> click('dlgRestack', 'mnuMiddle')
1
>>> click('dlgRestack', 'chk0')
1
>>> click('dlgRestack', 'btnApply')
1
>>> click('dlgRestack', 'chk0')
1
>>> click('dlgRestack', 'btnApply')
```

Comment: It worked ! thank you very much.. but I wonder how to select from this tab another choice ..
for example :
Extensions tab --> Arrange --> Restack ?

Comment: @Sara: I've updated my answer with an example to automate the Restack settings.

Comment: @Sara: You now have enough reputation to vote (^) on answers (See  [Why is voting important?](http://askubuntu.com/help/why-vote) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: Thank you very much for your effective help :).
I just have another question. I want to select an object in inkscape without using the mouse, by using Tab button in keyboard but I can't find the right command for this problem?

Comment: @Sara If the objects are already created, you could use the ldtp `keypress('<tab>')` function (See [LDTP:keypress](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/user-doc/dd/da2/a00192.html))

Comment: I have tried this command, but it didn't work as it writes tab space in terminal not on inkscape